# Snippet works on Chrome, Safari but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Added this bit of code to highlight active page in menu using Jquery 3.3.1 and it works on Chrome and Safari but not on Firefox.  Using a local version of Jquery.min.js and cleared cache but still not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you check Firefox's console for errors?

Comment: @parndepu and the OP is reading it...

Comment: @parndepu this code isn't writing to `window.location.href`

Comment: Have you checked that `$(this).prop('href')` and `window.location.href` actually match at any point?

Comment: my bad I will delete this. sorry.

Answer (score -1):

String comparison is case sensitive.. I think you can try these two methods to see if they work..

First: Use a toLowerCase method

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href').toLowerCase() == window.location.href.toLowerCase()) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
    });
});
```

Second: Console output what the browsers are seeing

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
    console.log("href : " + $(this).prop('href'));
    console.log("window.location.href : " + window.location.href);

    if ($(this).prop('href').toLowerCase() == window.location.href.toLowerCase()) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Get this error on Firefox Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: moz-extension://e214cadc-3019-ee4e-9085-be056e09540e/vendor/browser-polyfill.js
Source Map URL: browser-polyfill.js.map